# How to check for object containing some keys in jest?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I'm confused. I've just started to write tests with jest, and i cant figure out what is going on. Here is my output:

```
Expected value to equal:
  ObjectContaining {"field": "f1", "module": "m1", "rights": {"read": true}}
Received:
  {"_id": "5ae85cd0bc5ad3569bf66df8", "field": "f1", "module": "m1", "rights": {"read": true}}

Difference:

- Expected
+ Received

@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
- ObjectContaining {
+ Object {
+   "_id": "5ae85cd0bc5ad3569bf66df8",
    "field": "f1",
    "module": "m1",
    "rights": Object {
      "read": true,
    },
  183 |         ]),
  184 |       );
> 185 |       expect(user.acl[0]).toEqual(
  186 |           expect.objectContaining({ module: 'm1', field: 'f1', rights: {read: true}}),
  187 |       );
  188 |     });
```

I think its failing because `user` is a mongoose object.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `_id` from your object before comparing.

Alternatively, you should use `toMatchSnapshot()` (but still need to remove any keys that will change on each run.

Comment: this is definitely a bad answer, what about generated id? i need it. Also, i dont believe that there is no way of checking only part of object in jest.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can convert mongoose object to plain object by calling `user.toObject()` function. And everything works as expected.